# Global Variables and Tkinter with Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

So I am a programming novice, and I am trying to get this thread working. However, I am struggling with using the threading and tkinter. I think the issue is the global variables but I don't really know if that is the case. Any help is appreciated. (Also this code has been modified I need the thread as the function will have a loop eventually).

```
from tkinter import *
import serial
import threading

root = Tk()
root.title("MIDI Piano")
root.geometry('250x250+250+250')

ser = None
clicked = StringVar()

COM_ports = ["COM1",
         "COM2",
         "COM3",
         "COM4",
         "COM5",
         "COM6",
         "COM7",
         "COM8",
         "COM9",
         "COM10"]

def serial_comms():
    global ser
    global clicked
    COM = clicked.get()
    ser = serial.Serial(COM, 9600)

clicked.set("COM1")

# note there are definitions here and other widgets 

# Widgets that need to be updated
COM_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Choose COM Port", padx=30, pady=30)
COM_frame.place(x=1, y=200)


COM_drop = OptionMenu(COM_frame, clicked, *COM_ports)
COM_drop.pack()

COM_button = Button(COM_frame, text="Execute Port Selection", 
command=threading.Thread(serial_comms).start())
COM_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This code will make the button unusable or cannot click more than once. Use `command=lambda: threading.Thread(serial_comms).start()`.

Comment: Hi, this still causes the code to freak out - now the drop down menu won't even allow a click?

Comment: It should, recheck your code

Comment: @CoolCloud It should be `command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=serial_comms).start()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Oh yes, `target`.